# How to execute four threads consecutively one by one in java?

Tags: java

Want to implement something based on consecutive execution, but have to provide each thread's output to the next one's input. So, give me any suggestion.

Ex: 4 players are playing caroms, All 4 must be involved in the play.
Each one's output is a dependency to the next player. This is the scenario. So, would like to use threads!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If each thread has to wait for the previous one to end then you don't need threads.  Just execute the four tasks in sequence on one thread.

Comment: For the scenario you have listed you do not need threads. However to wait for some thread to finish,  look at the documentation for join().